# Can you recommend wiki, forum, blog & cms plugins for an existing Rails app or should I go the route of Engines?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, content-management-system, wiki, forum

I have an existing Rails internal app, that handles inventory, invoicing, order taking, labeling, data imports/exports, etc, etc.

Now I need to add blog, cms, forum and wiki functionality to it. It seems silly to try to roll out my own solutions when there are already some out there.  So I was wondering if people could recommend based on their experience:

- Are there good plugins out there? (Which ones you had experience with?)
- Would you rather recommend to go the route of engines, and integrate RadiantCMS or similar apps? (please provide recommendations based on your integration experience)
- Or would you just bite the bullet and roll out your own?

Thank you.

P.S.: Right now the app is Rails 2.3, but it will get upgraded to Rail 3 in a year, when most gems/plugins that it depends on will be Rails 3 compatible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't want this quesiton to die in vain - so I'll answer it myself.

In no particular order and without recommending one or the other.  Please, forgive me if I missed something. Here some choices:

### Forum:

- http://forulio.com/
- https://github.com/chipiga/forum_engine
- https://github.com/radar/rboard
- https://github.com/courtenay/altered_beast
- http://code.google.com/p/opinionforum/ ( no docs, but code is available)
- https://github.com/kaichen/wicked
- https://github.com/revworks/fringe_forum
- https://github.com/shayarnett/merbums
- https://github.com/elliottcable/fora
- https://github.com/eadz/savage-beast
- https://github.com/shirkevich/ultimate-beast
- https://github.com/Gazer/simple-forum
- https://github.com/mutle/fu2
- https://github.com/mutle/fu2
- https://github.com/marten/opinionated-forum

### Bog:

- http://www.mephistoblog.com/
- https://github.com/fdv/typo
- http://www.enkiblog.com/

### CMS:

- http://www.radiantcms.org/
- http://refinerycms.com/
- http://slatecms.wvu.edu/
- http://webiva.org/
- http://www.railfrog.com/
- http://www.caseincms.com/
- http://adva-cms.org/
- https://github.com/onomojo/rojo
- http://rubricks.org/index_en.html

### Wiki:

- http://www.instiki.org/
- http://hikiwiki.org/en/
- http://ruwiki.rubyforge.org/ruwiki.cgi
- http://rubyforge.org/projects/minirubywiki/
- https://github.com/garrickvanburen/culwiki
- http://pimki.rubyforge.org/
- http://www.wagn.org/

Comment: Hi Nick, Thanks for the information! I am looking into adding CMS and Forum into my application as well. Have you had chance to integrate any of these into your application? If you did, I would love to hear about your experience.

Comment: Well this info is about 2 years old, so I know for sure of at least 3 new blog engines. I'm sure there are more in other categories as well. However I had moderate success using RadiantCMS - great plus - good docs. I ended up rolling my own forum solution, it was easier than integrating some  of these.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any plugins, but maybe you can rip apart [Radiant CMS](http://radiantcms.org/) or the Wiki feature of [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) yourself.